# jquery nested json object, traversing and creating select options by category

Tags: jquery, json, select, nested

I'm trying to create select options from  nested json objects by category, I'm having trouble getting the nested objects below the category.

a jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/2bitcoder/ms6bzjf0/2/  any help / guidance would be appreciated.

```
var data = 
    [
        {
            "Category": "Action Priority",
            "data": [
                {
                    "ID": 141,
                    "cfg_item": "Urgent",
                    "SortOrder": 1
                },
                {
                    "ID": 142,
                    "cfg_item": "High",
                    "SortOrder": 2
                },
                {
                    "ID": 143,
                    "cfg_item": "Medium",
                    "SortOrder": 3
                },
                {
                    "ID": 144,
                    "cfg_item": "Low",
                    "SortOrder": 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Category": "Action Status",
            "data": [
                {
                    "ID": 138,
                    "cfg_item": "Open",
                    "SortOrder": 1
                },
                {
                    "ID": 139,
                    "cfg_item": "Closed",
                    "SortOrder": 2
                },
                {
                    "ID": 140,
                    "cfg_item": "On Hold",
                    "SortOrder": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ];


$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    $.each(val, function (key, val) {
        if (val == 'Action Status') {
            // traverse the child objects and create the select options
            $.each(val, function (key, val) {
                // alert(key + " : " + val);
                $('#edit-Status').append('<option value="' + ID + '">' + cfg_item + '</option>');
            });
        }
        // alert(val);

    });
    if (val == 'Action Priority') {
        // traverse the child objects and create the select options
        $.each(val, function (key, val) {
            // alert(key + " : " + val);
            $('#edit-Priority').append('<option value="' + ID + '">' + cfg_item + '</option>');
        });
    }
//  alert(val);});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is commented a bit to help you see where you were going off track

```
// loop outer array, each object in array has 2 properties `Category (string)` and `data (array)`
$.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
    var $select;
    // category determines which `select` element
    if (obj.Category == 'Action Status') {
        $select = $('#edit-Status');
    } else {
        $select = $('#edit-Priority');
    }
    // option parsing is the same for both types

    // loop over the `data` property array
    $.each(obj.data, function (dataIndex, dataObj) {           
        var option = '<option value="' + dataObj.ID + '">' + dataObj.cfg_item + '</option>'
        $select.append(option);
    });
});
```

Assumes you only have 2 categories

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ms6bzjf0/3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You don't need so many levels of looping. In the outer loop, just check `val.Category`. Then in your next level, you need to loop over `val.data`, and you need to access those objects' properties using `.ID` and `.cfg_item`.

You should avoid using the same variables in each `$.each()` loop, it's confusing.

```js
var data = 
    [
        {
            "Category": "Action Priority",
            "data": [
                {
                    "ID": 141,
                    "cfg_item": "Urgent",
                    "SortOrder": 1
                },
                {
                    "ID": 142,
                    "cfg_item": "High",
                    "SortOrder": 2
                },
                {
                    "ID": 143,
                    "cfg_item": "Medium",
                    "SortOrder": 3
                },
                {
                    "ID": 144,
                    "cfg_item": "Low",
                    "SortOrder": 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Category": "Action Status",
            "data": [
                {
                    "ID": 138,
                    "cfg_item": "Open",
                    "SortOrder": 1
                },
                {
                    "ID": 139,
                    "cfg_item": "Closed",
                    "SortOrder": 2
                },
                {
                    "ID": 140,
                    "cfg_item": "On Hold",
                    "SortOrder": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  switch (val.Category) {
    case 'Action Status':
      target = $('#edit-Status');
      break;
    case 'Action Priority':
      target = $('#edit-Priority');
      break;
    default:
      target = null;
  }
  if (target) {
    $.each(val.data, function(key2, item) {
      target.append('<option value="' + item.ID + '">' + item.cfg_item + '</option>');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="edit-Status"></select>
<br>
<select id="edit-Priority"></select>
```